# Provide Suggestions for Permission Requests (Dialogflow V2)

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I send the following response to the user, which asks him for the permissions to access name & location to deliver an order. How can I provide him suggestion chips for the google assistant app? Putting `suggestions:[{"title":"Yes"},{"title":"No"},{"title":"Cancel"}]` does not work...

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "systemIntent": {
        "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
        "data": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
          "optContext": "To deliver your order",
          "permissions": [
            "NAME",
            "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send a permission request back to the Assistant in your action, Google handles that step of the conversation in its entirety. Adding suggestion chips is not something that you can send back.

Comment: that's what I thought, but actually Google doesn't provide any suggestion chips. Is that normal or are there any further configurations that have to be done?

Comment: Sending suggestion chips is something that would fall on the job of Google. As Google doesn't send any suggestion chips, this is working as intended, at least from the developer's perspective.